# Can I modify this simple HTML form in order to send an e-mail?

Tags: php, html, web, xhtml, smtp

If you go in this page you can easy undestrand what I want to do: http://lnx.erusma.org/en/

At the bottom of the page I have an HTML module named: **Get in touch** that is composed by some fields thinked to represent an e-mail sender module.

The problem is that, at this time, this is only an HTML module and don't send an e-mail nowhere.

Its code infact is:

```
<form>
    <input id="name" title="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" size="23" style="width:94%" />
    <input id="email" title="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" size="23" style="width:94%" /> <br />
    <input id="subject" title="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" size="51" style="width:94%" /><br />
    <textarea id="message" cols="33" style="width:94%" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <a style="display:inline-block;background:#fff;border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;border-bottom: 2px solid #93B62A;padding:8px 12px;" href="#" style="float: left;">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Can I modify this code to send an e-mail with the inserted content (the content inserted in the form fields)?

What have I to do?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: HTML does not itself send email, you can easily write some PHP (since you tagged php) code for it on the action url

Comment: ok, can you help me to implement this thing?

Answer (score 2):

you will need to create a php/asp or any server side process to gather the values and send the email.

The form should be modified like this

```
<form method="post" action="myformsend.php">
<input id="name" title="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" size="23"     style="width:94%" />
<input id="email" title="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" size="23" style="width:94%" /> <br />
<input id="subject" title="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" size="51" style="width:94%" /><br />
<textarea id="message" cols="33" style="width:94%" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
<a style="display:inline-block;background:#fff;border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;border-bottom: 2px solid #93B62A;padding:8px 12px;" href="#" style="float: left;">Submit</a>
</form>
```

You can do it in traitional way or via ajax.

For the myformsend.php you can have something simple as this:

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

You can see more about it here -> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

Hope this help you

Comment: You have to make sure the server you are working on supports php. If not, check your hosting or with the Web Server Admin for the supported Server Side Codes or to implement PHP on that server.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Rely on the client to send the email
- Send the email from server-side code

The first option is simple enough, your form action would just be:

```
<form action="mailto:someemail@server.com">
```

Of course, I think your inputs would also need to match the names "subject" and "body", like this:

```
<input name="subject" type="text" />
<textarea name="body"></textarea>
```

Note these are `name` attributes, not `id` attributes.  Forms use the names.  So you should add `name` attributes to your form elements.

This won't actually "send an email" though.  This will instruct the web browser to try to open the user's default email client and compose a new message with those values as inputs.  That's probably not what you want.  Especially if the user doesn't have an email client, since nothing would happen in that case.

However, since you tagged the question with "PHP" then I'm assuming you also have server-side code as an option.  You can use [the PHP `mail()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to send email when handling the POST request from this form.  The first example on that page is pretty simple:

```
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
```

You just need to supply it with the strings that you want to use.  In the case of your form POST, your values would be in:

```
$_POST['name']
$_POST['email']
$_POST['subject']
$_POST['message']
```

(Again, this assumes you've added `name` attributes to your form elements.  I highly recommend you do that.)

With those string values you can build your call to `mail()`:

```
mail($_POST['email'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message']);
```

There's probably more you want to do, and there's a lot more you can do.  Take a look at the other examples in the linked PHP documentation.  You'll also very likely want to do some error checking, and definitely some user authorization before sending this email.  Having an open email gateway on your web page is something of value to spammers, and you may get your server blacklisted as a result.